# Netcat Failing with h_errno 11004: NO_DATA

Tags: networking, file-transfer, netcat

I have a win xp box running netcat v: `1.10 NT` as `non-listener`, and a kali linux box running as the listener, with netcat v: `1-10-41-1`.

When I run my listener on kali I get:

```
nc -v -w 60 -p 4444 -l < /home/user/file.py
listening on [any] 4444 ...
```

When I run my windows box to listen to kali, I get:

```
C:\Users\AUser\Desktop\Tools\netcat>nc -v -w 4 10.11.0.88 4444 > file.py
10.11.0.88: inverse host lookup failed: h_errno 11004: NO_DATA
(UNKNOWN) [10.11.0.88] 4444 (?) open
```

I tried doing thorough google searches, but didn't find anything that could help me out.

Current result: doesnt transfer file.

Desired Result: transfers the file.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This may have been a system issue on my end.

Although, I did get it to work!! Instead of using `netcat`, i used `ncat` the newer version.

Here is the syntax:
(windows): `ncat -l > file.py`

(linux): `ncat --send-only <win-ip> < /root/Desktop/file.py`

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: can you tell me where to download ncat